# Using Python code in Qgis for first time; troubles: error that it is not a valid layer

Tags: pyqgis, vector-layer

My first try of adding a simple vector layer is not working. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?
This is the code:

```
layer=iface.addVectorLayer("/C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/Thematicmapping/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp", "TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3","ogr")
```

I get a notification that the layer is not valid and that it cannot be added.

Comment: The leading slash before the 'C:' looks suspect.

Comment: merci beaucoup!!

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @Vince:

> The leading slash before the 'C:' looks suspect.

If you remove it, your layer will be loaded successfully:

```
layer=iface.addVectorLayer("C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/Thematicmapping/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp", "TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3","ogr")

if layer.isValid():
    print 'Layer loaded successfully'
```